# How do I stop users folder redirection

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, folder-redirection

I am setting up a new Windows Server 2003 machine, and with it I've set up a new Group Policy that includes Folder Redirection.

I accidentally linked this new GP to the wrong OU, and Folder Redirection was applied when i did not want it to be.

I've unlinked and linked in to the correct OU, but users who had this GP applied are still having their folders redirected and synced.

How can I stop this happening? I renamed a profile (rather than deleting) and the user could not log in correctly, suggesting that the redirected folder is still being used for the profile, and I do not want that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, you have to ensure that you set the 'Redirect the folder back to the local userprofile location when policy is removed' setting when initially setting up the GPO

So in this case, I have to add Folder Redirection that is not wanted, ensuring that I select the setting above, and then disable it once the policy has taken effect. A bit backwards, but fortunately simple enough.

Please see the [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888203) by MS for more information.